# Altbeacon Library not scanning when device locked

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, beacon, altbeacon

I know that there are a lot of questions regarding the altbeacon library especially when it is running in the background. However I could not find any question that is discussing the same problem I have and thus I am asking a new one.

On my android 7.1.1 device I am using the Xamarin Bindings of the altbeacon library with version 2.7.0. When app is in background and the phone is not locked, the app starts scanning after the configured interval and also finds the correct beacon. However when the phone is locked, the app stops getting any scan results immediately. Moreover, the altbeacons debug messages indicate, that the library starts scanning when the phone is locked, however no scan results are ever found.

The app has the location permission. 
Might the problem stem from the old version of the altbeacon library. Also, the logs say `starting non-filtered scan in SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY`, might it be problematic, that the scan is unfiltered?

Please see the logs below:

**App in background but phone not locked:**

```
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 1106 milliseconds
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 103 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] starting a new scan cycle
[CycledLeScanner] starting a new bluetooth le scan
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] starting non-filtered scan in SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY
[BluetoothAdapter] STATE_ON
[BluetoothLeScanner] onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=10 mClientIf=0
[CycledLeScanner] Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 60000 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{8c4a54e: android.os.BinderProxy@e6c566f}
[CycledLeScanner] Scan started
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
...
```

**Then when I lock the phone:**

```
[CycledLeScanner] Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 48903 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{8c4a54e: android.os.BinderProxy@e6c566f}
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 0201021aff4c0002156c2e3172768b4d3ea47b01470fe908a40000019bc80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 0201021aff4c0002156c2e3172768b4d3ea47b01470fe908a40000019bc80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 0201021aff4c0002156c2e3172768b4d3ea47b01470fe908a40000019bc80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
[BeaconParser] This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
[BeaconService] beacon detected : id1: 6c2e3172-768b-4d3e-a47b-01470fe908a4 id2: 0 id3: 411
[BeaconService] This region (id1: 31c668d3-6b81-4be2-876c-228ed4f88df8 id2: 0 id3: 411) does not match beacon: id1: 6c2e3172-768b-4d3e-a47b-01470fe908a4 id2: 0 id3: 411
[BeaconService] looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] with service uuid: 0000fe61-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] with service uuid: 0000fe61-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] with service uuid: 0000fe61-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] with service uuid: 00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 09
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type 16: 020102100948617070696d65746572204b525244041602184103020218000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 22, endIndex: 24
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 020102100948617070696d65746572204b525244041602184103020218000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 09
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type 16: 020102100948617070696d65746572204b525244041602184103020218000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 22, endIndex: 24
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 020102100948617070696d65746572204b525244041602184103020218000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] with service uuid: 0000fe61-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 08
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 03
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 12, endIndex: 26
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 020106020800030361fe10ff030000601d00000444032cc4de291216ff030000601d00000444032cc4de2988c626820af412000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 13
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0aff4c00100503103782db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[CycledLeScannerForLollipop] got record
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a1aff4c000c0e088fbb195d19bf24efde97ca7c7310050b10004a980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 02011a1aff4c000c0e088fbb195d19bf24efde97ca7c7310050b10004a980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2, endIndex: 22
[BeaconParser] Ignoring pdu type 01
[BeaconParser] Processing pdu type FF: 02011a1aff4c000c0e088fbb195d19bf24efde97ca7c7310050b10004a980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a1aff4c000c0e088fbb195d19bf24efde97ca7c7310050b10004a980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[BeaconParser] This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 16ff06000109210a2c1b17cda8a04d6f6e696b612d5043000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[CycledLeScanner] Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 47897 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{8c4a54e: android.os.BinderProxy@e6c566f}
[CycledLeScanner] Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 46890 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{8c4a54e: android.os.BinderProxy@e6c566f}
[CycledLeScanner] Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 45880 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{8c4a54e: android.os.BinderProxy@e6c566f}
[CycledLeScanner] Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 44875 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{8c4a54e: android.os.BinderProxy@e6c566f}
[CycledLeScanner] Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 43865 milliseconds
[CycledLeScanner] Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{8c4a54e: android.os.BinderProxy@e6c566f}
```

Comment: Unfiltered bluetooth scans are blocked with the screen off only on Android 8.1+, and the Android Beacon Library was updated to address this in version 2.13.  I don't think this is your problem because you say you experience the problem on Android 7.1.1.  The logs you posted show that bluetooth detections are happening when you lock the phone.  So I suspect the problem is something in the callbacks to your app when the screen is locked.  I am not a Xamarin expert, but I would investigate any app life cycle changes that happen on Xamarin when the screen is locked.  Do other async callbacks work?

Comment: What device model is this seen on?  Please also look for system level log messages (do not filter for your app)

Comment: Actually, BT detections are not happening when the phone is locked. Only the first second after I lock the phone, but afterwards no more detections take place. I think the log is a little bit misleading in that regard. I am using a ZTE - z385 phone. I'll take a look at the system level log soon! thanks anyway!

Comment: Also other callbacks are fired (e.g.: BT disconnects)

Comment: It's possible this is a device-specific issue, meaning that the ZTE - z385 has a custom Android ROM that blocks bluetooth scans with the screen off.  [Huawei devices do something similar](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/554).  To check this, you might try using the reference app out-of-the-box to see if it can detect in the background on that device.  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference  System level logs may tell you if bluetooth scans are being blocked by the OS with the screen off